# Windows 10 boot and HDD partitions vanished

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10

This is my first post here please ignore if i miss some rules thank you. I was trying to make my PC dual boot with windows 10 already installed. The screen that appears after choosing something else from ubuntu 17.10 installation process i never saw the partition i made on windows 10 for the ubuntu installation files. i clicked the revert button and now i'm not able to get back into my windows 10. i have important pictures on drives, i need to recover them. [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/26478152/) is the information i got from boot-repair software. Please help me to get back to my windows 10 OS. Thank You.

Comment: You choose the erase entire hard drive install option LVM or LVM with encryption. That means Windows is totally gone. Best just to restore from your backups. You cannot use Windows to create Linux partitions. And if you did not turn off Windows fast start up, Linux will not see any Windows NTFS partitions as they are hibernated.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have my windows backup. i guess best for me is to install ubuntu try and than recover my data somehow. is it possible?

Comment: The best option for dual booting is choosing the option "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows". This option let you shrink Windows "C" drive to create a partition and install Ubuntu. However,  as the entire HDD is erased, just install Ubuntu/Windows then try to recover data with third-party softwares. It's probably better if you install Windows first then try to recover everything and then install Ubuntu(if you want). Windows has better quality software for this stuff.

Comment: yeah, i'm trying with testdisk it's on deep scan; hope this work :)

Comment: Do not use disk as every bit of use is overwriting more data. You will not be able to recover all data or working Windows. Photorec can scan drive for anything that looks like a file, but it does not find names, just file types. Some say Windows tools may work better for NTFS scanning.